# bind to static property in app.xaml.cs for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding

How can I bind to a static boolean property defined in App.xaml.cs in my wp7 page.xaml?

I have a static property - IsTrial (boolean) defined in App.xaml.cs and would like to bind to it to hide/show the AdControl from microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight 3 (upon which the Windows Phone 7 framework is built) does not support the `x:Static` markup extension, so you cannot bind to a static property. However, you can expose a "regular" read-only property that simply returns the value of the static property.

```
private static bool IsTrialCore
{
  get { // Your logic here. }
}

public bool IsTrial
{
  get { return IsTrailCore; }
}
```

Comment: Derek, how would I use this property in the binding if it is not static.  Can you please show an example in xaml?

Comment: Actually, it would make sense to explose the non-static property in your view model (or code-behind) and bind to that: `"{Binding IsTrial}"`. If you're not using a view model, then you'll need to add `this.DataContext = this;` in your page's constructor.

Comment: Hi Derek. This all works on the Page, but not in App.xaml's resources. Do you know how to bind in resources?